# Alinear formulario Bootstrap TextArea

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Como puedo organizar mi formulario, estoy utilizando bootstrap pero no puedo organizar el campo descripción que es un textarea debajo de los otros dos inputtext

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el codigo que estoy utilizando

```
<form>
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <?= $form->field($model, 'idArea')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <?= $form->field($model, 'Nombre')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-row">
            <?= $form->field($model, 'Descripcion')->textarea(['maxlength' => true, 'style' => 'width:40%']) ?>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: La estoy utilizando con Yii2 es bootstrap 2.0.7

Comment: Hiciste una edición a la pregunta y cambiaste TOTALMENTE el problema planteado inicialmente.

Comment: El problema que planteaste era que no podías alinear el textarea debajo de los dos input. Una vez solucionado (con el código que proporcioné), si tienes un nuevo problema, puedes formular una nueva pregunta.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74366/discussion-between-sebastian-salazar-and-shaz).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si entiendo bien el problema:

> *no puedo organizar el campo descripción que es un textarea debajo de los otros dos inputtext*

Entonces para ponerlo debajo de los dos input y que ocupe "todo el ancho" tienes varias opciones:

1. Utiliza la clase `col` en cada elemento de la fila:

   ```html
   <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
   <form>
     <div class="form-row">
       <div class="col">
         <label for="exampleInput1">First name</label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInput1" placeholder="First name">
       </div>
       <div class="col">
         <label for="exampleInput2">Last name</label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control"  id="exampleInput2" placeholder="Last name">
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="form-row">
       <div class="col">
         <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Example textarea</label>
         <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3"></textarea>
       </div>
     </div>
   </form>
   ```
2. Utiliza la sintaxis típica de la grilla de 12 columnas:

   ```html
   <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
   <form>
     <div class="form-row">
       <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
         <label for="exampleInput1">First name</label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInput1" placeholder="First name">
       </div>
       <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
         <label for="exampleInput2">Last name</label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control"  id="exampleInput2" placeholder="Last name">
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="form-row">
       <div class="col">
         <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Example textarea</label>
         <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3"></textarea>
       </div>
     </div>
   </form>
   ```